# A "not equals" predicate slows query down tremendously; what can I do about it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What I'm trying to do is to modify an existing view to exclude certain records from the view. So I have joined the appropriate table and in the `WHERE` clause, I have added `PSRD.RoleID <> 153` but this makes the query go from taking approximately 15 seconds to running for over 5 minutes. I have also tried in the `JOIN` to remove all `RoleID`s of 153 and it didn't affect the run time.

Suggestions?

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT
PEVD.EmployeeID [EmployeeID],
P.PersonID,
SEM.eventbegindate [EventDate], 
LEFT (CONVERT (varchar(20), MIN (PSD.StartTime), 108), 5) [StartTime],
LEFT (CONVERT (varchar(20), MAX (PSD.EndTime), 108), 5) [EndTime],
CASE WHEN DAY (MIN (PSD.StartTime)) <> DAY (MAX (PSD.EndTime)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsAddDay]
FROM
StaffingEventMaster SEM
INNER JOIN StaffingEventShiftDetail SESD on SEM.EventID = SESD.EventID
INNER JOIN PeopleStaffingDetail PSD on SESD.ShiftID = PSD.ShiftID
INNER JOIN People P on PSD.PersonID = P.PersonID
INNER JOIN PeopleEmployeeValueDetail PEVD on PEVD.PersonID =P.PersonID
INNER JOIN PeopleStaffingRoleDetail PSRD on P.PersonID = PSRD.PersonID AND PSRD.RoleID <> 153
LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteMaster SM on SEM.SiteID = SM.SiteID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DriveMaster DM on SEM.DriveID = DM.DriveID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts A on DM.AccountID = A.AccountID
WHERE
--PSRD.RoleID <> 153 and
LEN (PEVD.EmployeeID) > 0
GROUP BY
PEVD.EmployeeID,
P.PersonID,
SEM.EventBeginDate
```

I've included two execution plans - one with <> in the WHERE clause and the original.

[Execution Plan With <> in Where Clause](http://www.filedropper.com/wherenotequal)

[Original Query](http://www.filedropper.com/withoutfilter)

Comment: You should include query plans for both cases, with and without the criteria

Comment: That is because <> is nonSARGable. It means that it has to look at every single row to determine if the predicate is met or not. Change this to > 153 OR < 153

Comment: This is also non-SARGable: `LEN (PEVD.EmployeeID) > 0`. It must apply the function on every single `EmployeeID` to see it meets the condition.

Comment: Sean - Thanks for the reply but these are roles and I want to return all values that are not role ID of 153.

Comment: Could you load the original query results into a temp table and then query from that with the `<> 153` clause?

Comment: Agree with Sean - change "PSRD.RoleID <> 153" to logical equivalent  "(PSRD.RoleID > 153 or PSRD.RoleID <  153)"

Comment: The query in the question - with the `<> 153` commented out - includes the same condition in the join criteria for the relevant table (not commented out). Is this an accurate representation of the original query? Surely it is functionally equivalent to the amended query?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jpDqe.png

Comment: Compare the query plan with and without the condition `<> 153`, then add query hints to bring them into line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying `NOT (PSRD.RoleID = 153)`and there does not seem to be a reason for the 3 left joined tables. I also wonder if this test `LEN(PEVD.EmployeeID) > 0` is really required; do you really have zero length strings in such a field?

```
SELECT
      PEVD.EmployeeID [EmployeeID]
    , P.PersonID
    , SEM.eventbegindate [EventDate]
    , LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(20), MIN(PSD.StartTime), 108), 5) [StartTime]
    , LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(20), MAX(PSD.EndTime), 108), 5) [EndTime]
    , CASE
            WHEN DAY(MIN(PSD.StartTime)) <> DAY(MAX(PSD.EndTime)) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
      END [IsAddDay]
FROM StaffingEventMaster SEM
      INNER JOIN StaffingEventShiftDetail SESD ON SEM.EventID = SESD.EventID
      INNER JOIN PeopleStaffingDetail PSD ON SESD.ShiftID = PSD.ShiftID
      INNER JOIN People P ON PSD.PersonID = P.PersonID
      INNER JOIN PeopleEmployeeValueDetail PEVD ON PEVD.PersonID = P.PersonID
      INNER JOIN PeopleStaffingRoleDetail PSRD ON P.PersonID = PSRD.PersonID
      /*
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteMaster SM ON SEM.SiteID = SM.SiteID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN DriveMaster DM ON SEM.DriveID = DM.DriveID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts A ON DM.AccountID = A.AccountID
      */
WHERE NOT (PSRD.RoleID = 153)
      /* AND LEN(PEVD.EmployeeID) > 0 suggest you replace this line */
      AND PEVD.EmployeeID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
      PEVD.EmployeeID
    , P.PersonID
    , SEM.eventbegindate
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried the `NOT (PSRD.RoleID = 153)` and that worked pretty well. And for the `LEN (PEVD>EmployeeID) > 0`, that column contains NULL values so that would eliminate the NULLS. Not every person in this table has an employee ID.  And lastly, the 3 LEFT OUTER JOINS were not necessary so they were removed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help but looks like there were a couple tables you are not using

```
SELECT PEVD.EmployeeID [EmployeeID],
       PSD.PersonID,
       SEM.eventbegindate [EventDate], 
       LEFT (CONVERT (varchar(20), MIN (PSD.StartTime), 108), 5) [StartTime],
       LEFT (CONVERT (varchar(20), MAX (PSD.EndTime), 108), 5)   [EndTime],
       CASE WHEN DAY (MIN (PSD.StartTime)) <> DAY (MAX (PSD.EndTime)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsAddDay]
  FROM StaffingEventMaster SEM
  JOIN StaffingEventShiftDetail SESD 
    on SEM.EventID = SESD.EventID
  JOIN PeopleStaffingDetail PSD 
    on SESD.ShiftID = PSD.ShiftID
  JOIN PeopleEmployeeValueDetail PEVD 
    on PEVD.PersonID = PSD.PersonID
   and LEN (PEVD.EmployeeID) > 0
  JOIN PeopleStaffingRoleDetail PSRD 
    on PSRD.PersonID = PSD.PersonID
   AND PSRD.RoleID <> 153
 GROUP BY PEVD.EmployeeID,
          PSD.PersonID,
          SEM.EventBeginDate
```

this might be faster

```
    SELECT PEVD.EmployeeID [EmployeeID],
           PSD.PersonID,
           SEM.eventbegindate [EventDate], 
           LEFT (CONVERT (varchar(20), MIN (PSD.StartTime), 108), 5) [StartTime],
           LEFT (CONVERT (varchar(20), MAX (PSD.EndTime), 108), 5)   [EndTime],
           CASE WHEN DAY (MIN (PSD.StartTime)) <> DAY (MAX (PSD.EndTime)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsAddDay]
      FROM StaffingEventMaster SEM
      JOIN StaffingEventShiftDetail SESD 
        on SEM.EventID = SESD.EventID
      JOIN PeopleStaffingDetail PSD 
        on SESD.ShiftID = PSD.ShiftID
      JOIN PeopleEmployeeValueDetail PEVD 
        on PEVD.PersonID = PSD.PersonID
       and LEN (PEVD.EmployeeID) > 0
      JOIN PeopleStaffingRoleDetail PSRD1 
        on PSRD1.PersonID = PSD.PersonID
       AND PSRD1.RoleID < 153
      JOIN PeopleStaffingRoleDetail PSRD2 
        on PSRD2.PersonID = PSD.PersonID
       AND PSRD2.RoleID > 153
     GROUP BY PEVD.EmployeeID,
              PSD.PersonID,
              SEM.EventBeginDate
```

Comment: Thanks Frisbee - the second query was faster and you were right, the 3 LEFT OUTER JOINS were not necessary so I removed those.